# Open second jquery dialog failed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to open a jquery dialog inside another one. The first dialog opens but the second dialog raises an error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

All pages have same javascript files as reference.

The javascript to handle the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    stack: true,
    open: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#myIframe').attr('src','http:Order/orderForm.aspx');
    }
});

$('#dialogBtn').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});

function openSecond(id){
    $("#"+id).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 300,
        stack: true,
        open: function(ev, ui) {
            $('#myIframe2').attr('src','http:Order/orderDetail.aspx');
        }
    });
}
```

There is my div for first dialog box on parent page.

```
<div id="dialog" ><iframe id="myIframe" src=""  />  </div>
```

Below is the one on the child page

```
<div id="dialog2" ><iframe id="myIframe2" src=""  />  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code where you call `openSecond()`?

Comment: @Damitoma, <label style="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="openSecond('dialog2');">Order Detail</label>

Comment: Don't self close `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery UI. This is the official API https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/. You can download it [here](https://jqueryui.com/download/). And don't self-close `<iframe>`

Comment: I have them on my page. <script language="javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and my javascript file as  <script language="javascript" src="../scripts/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> for all pages

Comment: jquery and jquery ui are two different package